# Why does my script make my "dash" have a seemingly random duration and how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to coding. I've been trying to Frankenstein basic tutorials into something of my own and it seems ive finally hit a wall. I'm really not sure what is causing this and would like some help to weed out the problem.
at the moment when I press the dash button (left shift) my character dashes in the direction he is facing but for a random duration. I would like it to be consistent and working properly.
Thanks in advance!
PS: Sorry for the long script, it contains everything to do with player movment.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Player Movement
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public float dashSpeed;
    public float startDashTime;
    public float dashCooldownTime = 2;
    private float nextFireTime = 0;


    public Animator animator;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float moveInput;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private float jumpTimeCounter;
    public float jumpTime;
    private bool isJumping;
    private float dashTime;
    public int direction;
    void Start()
    {
        animator.GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        dashTime = startDashTime;
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        if (direction < 1 )
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        // Moving
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);


        }
        else if (moveInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
        // Jumping
        if (isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("IsJumping");
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == true)
        {
            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
      
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                isJumping = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            

            isJumping = false;
        }
        if (isGrounded == false)
        {

            animator.SetBool("Grounded", false);
            
        }
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Grounded", true);
        }
        // Dashing

        if (Time.time > nextFireTime) 
        {
            if (direction == 0)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("beaners");
                    nextFireTime = Time.time + dashCooldownTime;
                    if ((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 180))
                    {
                        Dashleft();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DashRight();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(dashTime <= 0)
            {
                direction = 0;
                dashTime = startDashTime;
                
            }
            else
            {
                dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;

          
            }
        }
    }
    void Dashleft()
    {
        direction = 1;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashSpeed;
    }
    void DashRight()
    {
        direction = 1;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * dashSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Random duration is because of the use of `Rigidbody2D`.
See in Unity `Rigidbody2D` is responsible for each and every single physical interaction. It mean forces from player like player movement and forces from your environment like friction and collision.

Here what is happening is that when your player is dashing there is also player movement force, which is also applied on your player's `Rigidbody2d`. And friction of ground on which your player is running/dashing on.
I've added a comment on parts that I've changed.

#### Updated part of your script:

```
private bool isDashing;
.
.
.
void Update()
{

//Added: putting a Condition to check if you player is not dashing, if it is then
//player won't be able to do anything, As I've scene and done in many games. if you
//don't want this remove it and see what happens, this is not tested so sorry if there
//is something that is not working as intended.

 //dashing condition check
 if(!isDashing)
 {
    // Moving
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    if (moveInput > 0)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        animator.SetBool("Moving", true);


    }
    else if (moveInput < 0)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
    }
    // Jumping
    if (isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("IsJumping");
        isJumping = true;
        jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
        
        //Changed: use Add force method instead of changing the velocity.
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        //rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == true)
    {
        if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            //Changed: Same this rb.AddForce...
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            //rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        

        isJumping = false;
    }
    if (isGrounded == false)
    {

        animator.SetBool("Grounded", false);
        
    }
    if (isGrounded == true)
    {
        animator.SetBool("Grounded", true);
    }
}
//dashing condition ends

    // Dashing

    if (Time.time > nextFireTime) 
    {
        //Here your Dash timer ends.
        isDashing = false;
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("beaners");
                nextFireTime = Time.time + dashCooldownTime;

                //Here your Dash timer Starts.
                isDashing = true;
                if ((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 180))
                {
                    Dashleft();

                }
                else
                {
                    DashRight();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(dashTime <= 0)
        {
            direction = 0;
            dashTime = startDashTime;
            
        }
        else
        {
            dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;

      
        }
    }
}
```

visit [Unity - Scripting API: Rigidbody2D.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) hope it helps.
`Happy Coding`

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I tried both writing in the code myself on my current script and copy pasting your entire edited script into its respective paths but I couldn't get it to work. I had to change my jumpForce value so it could suit the new addForce part. My character still has what seems random dashing lengths. Thanks for you help though, it means a lot when someone takes time out of their day to try to help someone.

Comment: You have a collider on you player, right. try adding a [PhysicsMaterial2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html) on that collider with ```0 friction value``` that might help.

Comment: Even with the character having 0 friction materials, the dash is still random. I wonder what is causing it